# ggvis - How to show different variables in barchart, and select any or more dynamically

Tags: r, bar-chart, ggvis

i have this data.frame:

```
    Campanas1     variable     sessions
1   Adwords       sumResults    69
2   Campa�as     sumResults     2
3   Directo       sumResults    10947
4   Email         sumResults    413
5   Referencias   sumResults    12991
6   SEO           sumResults    37693
7   Social Media  sumResults    5993
8   Others        sumResults    2
```

I've made a bar chart with this code:

```
Sesiones_Campanas1 %>% ggvis(~Campanas1, ~sessions, fill := "red") %>% layer_bars()
```

**Question: How to put a selector for every/all Sources (from Campanas1)?**

My attemp:

```
Sesiones_Campanas1 %>% ggvis(~Campanas1, ~sessions, fill := "red") %>%   layer_bars(input_select(label = "Fuente"),
                                                                              choices = c("Email", 
                                                                                "Directo", "Adwords",
                                                                                "Campanas1", "Referencias", "SEO",
                                                                                "Social Media"))
```

But i get this error:

```
Error: length(x) not equal to 1
```

[image: This is what i want, but with interactivity]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of a research I think I made it. The difficult part was to include the All-rows part in the drop-down menu. So, here it goes:

First of all you need 2 libraries to do it: `dplyr` and `stringi`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

selector <- c('Adwords', 'Campanas', 'Directo', 'Email',  'Others', 'Referencias', 'SEO', 'Social_Media', 'All' = 'Adwords_Campanas_Directo_Email_Others_Referencias_SEO_Social_Media' ) 
#the selector is a vector to include all your choices
```

And the actual code that does what you need:

```
Sesiones_Campanas1  %>%  #the table
  ggvis(~Campanas1, ~sessions, fill := "red") %>% #the ggvis object
  filter(stri_detect_fixed(eval(input_select(choices=selector, label='Fuente' )) , Campanas1) ) %>%   #the difficult part. You need to use filter and stri_detect_fixed with the input select to get exactly what you need.
  layer_bars() #plot bars
```

I cannot upload the interactive graph (I think) so I ll upload the static `all` graph (But you can see the drop-down box and all of the choices there).

P.S. If the x-axis labels won't appear correctly it is because you need to increase the graph size (works both on Rstudio and on the browser)

P.S.2 A few words on how the `filter` line works: You need `eval` to evaluate the `input_select` outcome into a string so that it can then be matched with the `stri_detect_fixed` function. `filter` then decides which rows to be used.

And that's it!

[image]

**UPDATE**

In order to have the the 'all' sources selected at the beginning you need to specify the `selected` argument like this:

```
Sesiones_Campanas1  %>% 
  ggvis(~Campanas1, ~sessions, fill := "red") %>%
  filter(stri_detect_fixed(eval(input_select(choices=selector, label='Fuente', selected='Adwords_Campanas_Directo_Email_Others_Referencias_SEO_Social_Media' )) , Campanas1) ) %>%   
  layer_bars()
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thanks! I'm playing with the code, but...it always starts with just one "Source" selected. Who to make that all the variables are selected at start? It would be easier to do it with Shiny?

Comment: It can very easily happen with `ggvis` using the `selected` argument. Check the updated answer. No need to use shiny (ggvis uses shiny in the background anyway). Hope it helps!